# JavaMail to MTA security layer

Tags: jakarta-mail, postfix-mta

I want to use JavaMail (web app on Tomcat or JBoss) to compose and send mail through an externally hosted MTA and I want to learn more about the data security between the MTA and the Java API itself. I'm guessing there is some sort of transport layer security? I'm having a hard time finding anything, I don't seem to know what keywords to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches:

1. Use SSL/TLS to make the initial connection.
2. Use a plain text connection and then use the STARTTLS command to switch to SSL/TLS.

JavaMail supports both.  See the properties for the various protocol providers and the [SSLNOTES.txt](https://javamail.java.net/docs/SSLNOTES.txt) file.

Comment: I see. I thought those properties had to do with the transport of the mail between the MTAs. So if I were to register the javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory, that would be responsible for the connection from my app server to the MTA correct?

Comment: [You don't need no stinkin' socket factory!](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes)  :-)  Yes, the options I described above apply to the connection between the JavaMail client and the server.